# |ReactNative|-Conditional rendering ?: with Jest && Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

Good afternoon,
I have a component file structured like that globally :

```
  class Component ...

      render(){
           const {array} = this.props

           {!array.includes(value) ?
                (<View ...props
                    id="myComponent"/>
                      ....
                 </View>)  :

                (<View ...props
                   id="myOtherComponent"/>
                      ....
                </View>)
            }
        }
```

And in my test file, i'm doing the stuff like that :

```
describe('Testing Component', () => {
        test('conditional rendering', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Component array={[value]}/>);
        expect(wrapper.find(n => n.prop('id') === "myOtherComponent").exists(true))
    });
});
```

But even if I modify the props sent for the array, it always returned me `true`... What's the keyword to check that the nested component is actually verified and rendered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is in your `expect` argument.

1. I would use the `findWhere` function instead of `find`;
2. The `exists` method should not receive a parameter in this
   case, as it only receives Enzyme's Selectors and not booleans (you can read more about it [here](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/exists.html));
3. Add a `toBeTruthy` call to the `expect` line.

Here's a similar situation to yours that we have a test for and it works just fine:

```
it('tests name', () => {
  const mockComponent = shallow(<Component {...props} />);
  const textNode = mockComponent.findWhere(n => n.text() === props.name);
  expect(textNode.exists()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

So your test would end up looking like this:

```
describe('Testing Component', () => {
        test('conditional rendering', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Component array={[value]}/>);
        const node = wrapper.findWhere(n => n.prop('id') === 'myOtherComponent');
        expect(node.exists()).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Does `findWhere` manage the case if the component is actually a nested component and that my conditional render `<View> ` is not the main Parent ?

Comment: Alright seems to be working like a charm, I was close ;) Thank's for the help